# Amazon AWS KMS + Gradle: NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, intellij-idea, gradle

My `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.11.171'
}
```

My Java file:

```
import com.amazonaws.services.kms.AWSKMS;
import com.amazonaws.services.kms.AWSKMSClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.kms.model.GenerateDataKeyRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.kms.model.GenerateDataKeyResult;

import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public class KmsExample {

    private static final String KEYID = "arn:aws:kms:us-east-1:[userid]:key/[cmk id]";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AWSKMS kms = AWSKMSClientBuilder.defaultClient();

        GenerateDataKeyRequest dataKeyRequest = new GenerateDataKeyRequest();
        dataKeyRequest.setKeyId(KEYID);
        dataKeyRequest.setKeySpec("AES_128");

        GenerateDataKeyResult dataKeyResult = kms.generateDataKey(dataKeyRequest);

        String plaintextKey = StandardCharsets.UTF_8.decode(dataKeyResult.getPlaintext()).toString();

        String encryptedKey = StandardCharsets.UTF_8.decode(dataKeyResult.getCiphertextBlob()).toString();

        System.out.println(plaintextKey + " | " + encryptedKey);
    }

}
```

Simple enough. However, when I run my file it gives me `NoClassDefFoundError` error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
com/amazonaws/services/kms/AWSKMSClientBuilder
at KmsExample.main(KmsExample.java:13)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
com.amazonaws.services.kms.AWSKMSClientBuilder
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 6 more
```

In IntelliJ, I see my files have been imported fine, and all the JARS are there:
[image]

<kbd>Ctrl/Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> to jump to file declaration works fine, proving that the file is there.

So why am I still getting a NoClassDefFoundError?

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the dependency that contains `AWSKMSClientBuilder` class. Just add the following to your `build.gradle`:

```
compile group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'aws-java-sdk-kms', version: '1.11.171'
```